# Echo SQL query from voting table

Tags: mysql, sql, echo, voting-system

I have an image gallery with a vote function, and I'm trying to display the number of votes for each image from the database.

I have a Votes table with the following...

```
vote_id │ user_id │ session_id │ ip │ created_date │ status
```

I am trying to get the number of votes for each image to display (several images per page), but only 1 vote per ip and only within the last week (Mon to Sun).

I'm not a genius when it comes to this sort of thing, but this is what I have been able to do so far to get results in SQL. I've been getting a bit stuck trying to implement it into PHP...

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS Votes FROM 'vote'` (I know its basic but there you go)

Comment: If you want to get the number of votes for each image, where is the image_id stored?

Comment: the image id is stored in a table "image" 
image_id - image_name - image_caption - image_tag - image_url - mime - width - height - size - user_id - created_date

Comment: So how do you know which votes were for which image?

Comment: Is your image object extend any abstract object like post or something cause it's really tough to get the relation between image and vote

Comment: There is a "reg" table with reg_id which is shared as user_id in the other 2.

Comment: do you have any UML diagram?a class diagram is enough to help us :) waiting...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have one.

Comment: I know this is wrong but you may get a better idea of what i am trying to achieve '
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip, $user_id) AS Votes, WEEK(created_date) AS week_num FROM vote
group by WEEK(created_date)
order by week_num
WHERE week_num = $week_num'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is :)


`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS Votes, WEEK(created_date) AS week_num FROM 'vote'

group by WEEK(created_date)

order by week_num DESC`

Answer (score 2):

you have to group data:

`group by ip, week(created_date)`

Comment: I have `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS Votes, (SELECT WEEK(created_date) AS week_num FROM tcs_vote WHERE week_num= $weekNumber AND week_num= ('$weekNumber'));` but its coming up with Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ip' in 'field list'??

Answer (score 0):

You should have a column like image_id in the votes table. Then you can accomplish this by this query.

`SELECT image_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS Votes FROM vote GROUP BY image_id`